# Javascript resize event faulty

Tags: javascript, html, resize, dom-events

I don't know why this doesn't work:

```
window.addEventListener('load', setSize(), false);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSize(), false);

function setSize(){
    width = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(width);
}
```

It logs the width right after load, but it doesn't do that when I resize.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of executing the function (and passing the result) :

```
window.addEventListener('load', setSize(), false);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSize(), false);
```

you should pass a reference to the function:

```
window.addEventListener('load', setSize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSize, false);
```

The function will execute when the event listener triggers.

Comment: @OP - note that the difference is `setSize()` will pass THE RESULT as an argument, and `setSize` will pass the function itself as an argument. That is the difference.