# Javascript function not triggering on addEventListener resize

Tags: javascript, resize, addeventlistener

I read [the response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122336/javascript-resize-event-not-working) but as far as I can see my code matches up with the solution.

responsedemoscripts runs when the page loads. the first instance of balancecolumns runs but resizing will not trigger balancecolumns at all.

```
 function responsedemoscripts() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', balancecolumns);
    balancecolumns();
}


 function balancecolumns () {
    var longestColumn = 0;
    $('.contentitem').each(function () {
        longestColumn = Math.max(longestColumn, $(this).innerHeight());
        });
    $('.contentitem').height(longestColumn);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is putting the eventlistener in a function. This function will never trigger if you don't call it. BTW if you want to call balancecolumns on load you could do something like this: `window.onload=balancecolumns;` and later  `window.addEventListener('resize', balancecolumns, false);` or with your code snippet see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8ekpqcp/

Instead of this:

```
 function responsedemoscripts() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', balancecolumns);
    balancecolumns();
}
```

Do this:

```
  window.onload=balancecolumns;
  window.addEventListener('resize', balancecolumns, false);
```

Comment: "This function will never trigger if you don't call it."  I don't understand this.  responsedemoscripts does get called on load so why isn't the handler added  when responsedemoscripts runs?

Comment: Well your code snippet does not show that you are calling `responsedemoscripts`. However you code also works properly if you call `responsedemoscripts()`. See this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/n8ekpqcp/